# Using VLC over LAN

Tags: networking, lan

I don't want to stream a video.  I just want to use Windows File Explorer, browse to my LOCAL Cloud on my LAN, double-click a video (say MP4), and watch the movie -- all from my Windows 8.1 Laptop.  Currently, when I do that, VLC pop-up indicates that VLC cannot play the video.  It then goes into "not responding" mode, and I have to close VLC with Task Manager.  No log is created (after enabling logging and filename in preferences.  If I copy that same video to my local drive, all works fine.  Version is 2.2.4.

So how do I play video over LAN?

Comment: What happens if you copy the file from the cloud storage to your machine's drive and open it with VLC there?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question.  The solution is a wee bit of an inconvenience, but certainly not much more effort.

SOLUTION:  Open VLC, then "Toolbar - Media - Open File".  In that 'Open File' dialog, browse to the LAN location where the video is located, and open it.  The file can be on a mapped drive, or not -- in which case, just browse Network until the file is found.

As soon as I discovered that, it was an 'ah-ah' moment.  Years ago, while using MusicMatch Program, a similar Windows File Explorer error occurred.  I could not access music via the "new and better" Windows 8 File Explorer.  The solution there was to put the complete path into the playlists, instead of just a shortened path without a Drive:.

So it seems that with (at least) Windows 8 and above, the arguments passed from Windows Explorer to an application -- when double-clicking an object -- have changed.  The older applications do not understand the new format, and therefore, cannot open the object properly.  Leastwise that is my non-programmers reasoning.

In any event, I hope my little conversation can help others with similar problems.  Chow.